# Translation request: Boundedness of Cauchy integral on Lipschitz boundary

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, integral-operators, translation

The reference: *"L'intégrale de Cauchy définit un opérateur borné sur $L^2$ pour les courbes lipschitziennes"* (https://annals.math.princeton.edu/1982/116-2/p04) is written in French. Can we find a English version?